# how to add an automatic padding left to a div based on the position of another div

Tags: css

I have the following `footer` that is broken to 2 part: an upper part and a lower part:
[image]

The upper part of the `footer` contains 4 divs and its css has:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
```

While the lower part contains 3 divs (1 is completely empty) and also its css has:

```
display:flex
justify-content:space-between;
```

What I want is to make the unordered list that starts with `TERMS & CONDITIONS` in the bottom part of the `footer` to start just under the unordered list that ends with `BEST PLAYERS` in the upper part of the `footer`, so along this red line:
[image]

Comment: I think you can be give e.g `margin-left: -10px` to `unordered list that starts with TEAM & CONDITIONS`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is to rearrange you html code: Instead of making two rows footer, make it one row with two columns, the first column is for the logo and the second column divided into two rows as well, with three columns

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="your-logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">fixtures</div>
        <div class="col-4">latest tweets</div>
        <div class="col-4">follow</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">blank</div>
        <div class="col-4">terms & privary</div>
        <div class="col-4">social icons</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do i place the border-bottom of the logo div at the height as the other div